# IBM Doors 9.6 Tabs Strip for all opened modules/ documnets

Tags: tabs, ibm-doors

I'm using Doors 9.6 , in which each documents/module is opening in new separate window ,

how can I have single window with tab strip at bottom for all opened document/module?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in capability of DOORS 9.6. In short, you cannot have this. There are some options (though they are all somewhat unpalatable),which I have set out below.

Of course, it's possible to extend DOORS using the DXL scripting language. However, whilst it is possible build your own user interfaces in DOORS using the DXL scripting language, a tabbed module viewer would be a significant task.

As a DOORS user, administrator, trainer and DXL script author of ~20 years experience, I would say that a tabbed module editor, enabling all (or even the majority) of the capabilities of a DOORS Formal Module window, falls somewhere between a huge effort, and an impossibility.

There are others of similar experience who read and post here, who may think of something I haven't, so don't abandon hope...

Other options might be to:
(1) use DOORS Web Access (a web front-end to DOORS) - a very much slower and less robust alternative to the DOORS client;
(2) maximise all your DOORS module Windows on one screen, and use the [Alt]+[Tab] keyboard shortcut to jump between them (nearly as good as tabbing, but you still have lots of separate windows, and can't see at a glance what's open)